# How to write a Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I want to return all IDs with 1 phone (work first. if no work, then home. OR empty Phone)

TALBE 1

```
ID   Name
01      ab
02      cd
03       ef
```

Table2

```
ID  phone type
01   1111   work
01   1234   Home
02   2345   home
```

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Showing some effort would be great

Comment: left joined too many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this... notice the use of `ROW_NUMBER()` in the subquery to order rows by phone type priority, and the `CASE` expression used to assign those priorities. Also the condition on `rn` in the outer join condition; it must be in the `ON` clause of the outer join and **not** in a `WHERE` clause (putting it in a `WHERE` clause would undo the **outer** character of the join).

I include the `CREATE TABLE` statements if anyone wants to use them.

Note - the OP has both `'home'` and `'Home'` in the inputs; this illustrates why the phone types should be stored in a separate, small table and `table2` should point to that small table, instead of allowing free text in the `type` column.

```
create table table1 ( id, name ) as
  select 01, 'ab' from dual union all
  select 02, 'cd' from dual union all
  select 03, 'ef' from dual; 

create table table2 ( id, phone, type ) as
  select 01, 1111, 'work' from dual union all
  select 01, 1234, 'home' from dual union all
  select 02, 2345, 'home' from dual;

select t1.id, t1.name, sq.phone, sq.type
from   table1 t1 left outer join 
       ( select id, phone, type,
                row_number() over (partition by id
                  order by case type when 'work' then 0
                                     when 'home' then 1 end) as rn
         from   table2
       ) sq
       on t1.id = sq.id and sq.rn = 1
;

ID NAME PHONE TYPE
-- ---- ----- ----
 1   ab  1111 work
 2   cd  2345 home
 3   ef
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a left join twice on table2 and case when

```
select t1.id, t1.name, case when tb.phone is not null then tb.phone 
                            when ta.phone is not null then ta.phone 
                            else null 
                        end  phone
from table1 t1
left join table2 ta on t1.id = ta.id and ta.type = 'work'
left join table2 tb on t1.id= tb.id and tb.type = 'Home'
```

Comment: This seems quite inefficient - if there are five phone types, would you need to join five copies of table 2? Better to process table 2 first.

Comment: Actually  I do have more than 20 types defined in the table2